# Apache Camel enrich message with file content on request

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, cxf, apache-camel

I'm implementing RESTful service (using CXFRS component) which should return files for some requests. Each file is fetched by its id and extension, i.e. `restfulservice.com/path/file/1/pdf`. Each file once added never changes. Files should not be moved or deleted after fetching and generally they should be accessible concurrently. Here is part of my Camel context:

```
from("direct:fetchFile")
    .process(fetchFileProcessor) // set file.id & file.extension
    .bean(fileService, "fetchFile(${header.file.id}, ${header.file.extension})") // set body to filename
    .setHeader("CamelFileName", simple("${body}"))
    .choice()
        .when(header("file.extension").isEqualTo("xml"))
            .pollEnrich("file:///{{application.fileStorage.basePath}}/xml?noop=true", 500)
        .when(header("file.extension").isEqualTo("pdf"))
            .pollEnrich("file:///{{application.fileStorage.basePath}}/pdf?noop=true", 500)
    .end()
    .convertBodyTo(File.class)
    .bean(responseProvider, "getResponse(${body}, 200)");
```

The problem with this configuration is that response has non-empty body only for second(why?) request, without timeout set service enters on eternal loop on second request with debug message

```
DEBUG o.a.c.c.f.FileConsumer - Took 0.000 seconds to poll <base path>\xml
```

Apace Camel version is 2.10.4

Any help would be appreciated

**UPD1**:
There is warning on [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) page, saying 'pollEnrich does not access any data from the current Exchange'. But nothing changes if I add `fileName=${body}` to file URL

**UPD2**:
It seems like pollEnrich do not support dynamic `fileName` specified in URL ([link](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/pollEnrich-consumer-with-selector-td4939908.html)). Route at current moment:

```
from("direct:fetchFile")
    .process(fetchFileProcessor) // set file.id & file.extension
    .bean(fileService, "fetchFile(${header.file.id}, ${header.file.extension})") // set body to filename
    .choice()
        .when(header("file.extension").isEqualTo("xml"))
            .pollEnrich("file:///{{application.fileStorage.basePath}}/xml?fileName=${body}&noop=true", 500)
            .setHeader("asset.type", simple(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
        .when(header("file.extension").isEqualTo("pdf"))
            .pollEnrich("file:///{{application.fileStorage.basePath}}/pdf?fileName=${body}&noop=true", 500)
            .setHeader("asset.type", simple("application/pdf"))
    .end()
    .convertBodyTo(File.class)
    .process(multipartProcessor) // add file ass attachment to multipart body and set it as body
    .bean(responseProvider, "getResponse(${body}, 200)");
```

**UPD3**
I'm trying to to implement custom processor to use PollingConsumer with dynamic file names:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Long timeout = exchange.getIn().getHeader("file.timeout", Long.class);
    if (enrichUri == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("'file.url' header not set");
    }

    CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
    Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint(enrichUri);
    PollingConsumer consumer = endpoint.createPollingConsumer();
    consumer.start();

    Exchange consumedExchange;
    try {
        if (timeout == null || timeout < 0) {
            consumedExchange = consumer.receive();
        } else if (timeout == 0) {
            consumedExchange = consumer.receiveNoWait();
        } else {
            consumedExchange = consumer.receive(timeout);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssetNotFoundException(e);
    } finally {
        consumer.stop();
    }
    exchange.getIn().setBody(consumedExchange.getIn().getBody());
}
```

Now it returns file contents on first response, but on each succeeding request I got eternal loop of above log messages:

```
DEBUG o.a.c.c.f.FileConsumer - Took 0.000 seconds to poll <base path>\xml
```

**UPD4**
I've implemented dynamic route which is added before processing and removed after it. This method is described in [this](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/How-to-grab-a-only-one-file-with-camel-tp4930104p5508497.html) post in Apache Camel forum. Route uses above processor to consume file. The result is the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple way often is the best way. I refuse to deal with Apache Camel file component in this case and implemented following processor:

```
public class FileLoadingProcessor implements Processor {

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String filename = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class); // message body contains filename
    String filePath = exchange.getIn().getHeader("fileprocessor.filepath", String.class);

    if (filePath == null || filename == null) {
        // throw some custom exception
    }

    URI uri = new URI(filePath.concat(filename));
    File file = new File(uri);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.format("File %s not found on %s", filename, filePath));
    }

    exchange.getIn().setBody(file);
}
```

Now it's working like a charm

Comment: Can you show what the DSL looks like using your custom processor?  Is there a way to pass a custom processor to pollEnrich?