# How to call Rest API [XML Namespace] from Camel?

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb, apache-camel

How to call rest API (name space parameters) from Camel API.

I have the Rest API `http://10.1.1.1:8080/rest/student/add/1029` and the implementation is looks like

```
public String addStudent(@PathParam("studentId") int studentId, @Mapped(namespaceMap = {
               @XmlNsMap(namespace = "student.details")
}) JAXBElement<StudentType> studentData);
```

I have set the body content with xml payload and I am always getting null response when I try to call this API.
How to map nameSpace in Camel API. It's looks like nameSpace problem.

**Here's my code**

```
from("direct:start")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("POST"))
.setBody(simple("home\student.xml")))
.to("http://10.1.1.1:8080/rest/student/add/1029");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think simple("home\student.xml") can load the xml as you want.
You need to write java code to load the XML from the file, set it into the message body as you want.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I almost five days spent to find the result why Content-Type is not support. Conten-Type is always null even If i set the value for it. One of the forum you have mentioned like <setOutHeader><constant>"XXX"</constant></setOutHeader>. Still the problem persists even if i set as you said. Can you give me an IDEA to resolve this issue? (Version : 2.X)

Comment: You can specify the Accept header before send the request to service just like this: setHeader("Accept" , "text/xml")

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947523/apache-camel-enrich-message-with-file-content-on-request how a file can be read with a custom processor

Comment: If you want to put the xml into the message body. you should try to use simple("resource:file:/home/student.xml")